# iOS OTA download slow

Tags: ios, performance, ota

Our enterprise app can be download and installed through OTA, but the download speed is really slow (about 20K per sec). In the meantime, the Android app deployed to the same server can download up to 150K per sec, not the expressive, but fair enough for most of the users.

I've tried to download the IPA file directly, the download speed is almost even as the Android version, that said, the file server and the bandwidth are fine for file downloading.

So the question is, why the iOS version deploy system (itms-service) is so slow? and how to improve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, finally found that it's bandwidth problem, but still don't know why the download of Android APK still much faster than iOS IPA a lot.